# Ubuntu 10 server Postfix to relay on my ISP

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, postfix

I am still trying to get my local virtual box Ubuntu 10 server to work fine.
This time I cant send email from my local machine - lets say, to test some contact form, etc...

I want it to relay on my ISP or whatever it works.
Lots of tuts out there but its funny how linux people assume everone knows what they know - I'm learning, so anything more than - read that documentation, blablabla, would be much appreciate.

Comment: You want your computer to send it to your Ubuntu and Ubuntu must then send it to your ISP, who will send it to the recipient?

Comment: Its only a relay option.
If you install xampp or watever on windows, you just need to change your php.ini file to set your smtp, port and send_from and you done - from your local host you can test your forms, etc...
It looks like is not as simple on Linux - my ubuntu server is now my "localhost" and I can see through mail.log that it is being able to communicate to relay the messages - but its get bounced, queued, etc - Im missing something...

Comment: If you're trying to make your computer an SMTP-server, try your luck at http://serverfault.com.

Comment: It looks like I am looking for the wrong setup - according to this question http://superuser.com/questions/92760/just-want-to-send-emails-from-my-ubuntu-server-what-simple-smtp-server-solution one of the guys there (sajb) said something about nullmailer - http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/ and http://undesigned.org.za/2007/11/22/nullmailer-a-developers-best-friend.

I will give it a try and post the results back - my question was bad formulated - what I need is not a SMTP server, but a simple solution  to relay on my ISP SMTP server - its only a development enviromment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just post here what I found looking in a lot of place, blogs, forums, etc...
Most people just said: gave up - don't use postfix - what you need is not a SMTP server, but a simple relay solution.

Then I change postfix to ssmtp and now its working perfectly.
So as simple answer for what I wanted - the thing is, I was trying to complicate things without knowing really well what I was doing...

Lesson learned - using ssmtp now - because this is all I need - a development and test environment.

Thanks for the comments and help.